# How can I convert a 256-bit big endian integer to little endian in Python?

Tags: python, struct, endianness

Not too complicated, or so I would hope. I've got a 256-bit hexadecimal integer encoded as big endian that I need to convert to little endian. Python's struct module would usually suffice, but [the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) has no listed format with size even close to that which I need.

Using struct's non length specific types (though I could be doing this wrong) doesn't appear to work:

```
>> x = 'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000'
>> y = struct.unpack('>64s', x)[0] # Unpacking as big-endian
>> z = struct.pack('<64s', y) # Repacking as little-endian
>> print z
'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000'
```

Example code (what should happen):

```
>> x = 'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000'
>> y = endianSwap(x)
>> print y
'00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff'
```

Comment: You are packing and unpacking it as a string. Strings do not have endianness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `struct` module cannot cope with 256 bit numbers. So you must do your encoding manually.

First, you should convert it to bytes:

```
x = 'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000'
a = x # for having more successive variables
b = a.decode('hex')
print repr(b)
# -> '\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

This way you can reverse it [using @Lennart's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15759881/296974):

```
c = b[::-1]
# -> '\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'

d = c.encode('hex')
z = d
print z
# -> 00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: I'm still learning Python, so can someone clarify what the equivalent option is in Python 3.3? Also, so I understand, why is it not possible to do this with slicing? Why conversion to bytes?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> big = 'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000'
>>> big[::-1]
'00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff'
```

Comment: Not good, IMO. If the first byte is a `ef`, the resulting last byte becomes `fe` while it should be `ef`.

Comment: @glglgl Well, that depends in exactly what kind if big-endian it is. Your assumption of 8-bit small endian bytes with big-endian byte order is probably a good assumption. I just did the simplest thing. :-P